# Two QWidget in QMainWindow to have minimize button and window title

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    textEdit1 = new QTextEdit();
    textEdit1->setWindowTitle("First Notepad");
    textEdit2 = new QTextEdit();
    textEdit2->setWindowTitle("First Notepad");
    layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(textEdit1);
    layout->addWidget(textEdit2);

    newTab = new QWidget();
    newTab->setLayout(layout);

    ui->setupUi(this);
    setCentralWidget(newTab);
}
```

[image]

The above is my code sample of the `MainWindow` constructor. Ot has two `qTextEdits` which are in a `VerticalBox` layout. I want both the `textEdits` to have a title bar and minimize and maximize button so that at a time I can use one of them or both of them. But as you can see the output the Window Title bars are not there.

How can I make the Title bar appear? Why is it that `setWindowTitle("First Notepad")` do not display the Title?

If I am doing it wrong please suggest as what other way I can proceed. Any suggestion is welcome.

**What I am trying is like one MainWindow having multiple sub-windows with fixed positions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am trying is like one MainWindow having multiple sub-windows with fixed positions.

What you are looking for is probably a [`QMdiArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html) along with multiple [`QMdiSubWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdisubwindow.html).
As mentioned in the documentation of `QMdiArea:

> The QMdiArea widget provides an area in which MDI windows are displayed

Moreover:

> QMdiArea is commonly used as the center widget in a QMainWindow to create MDI applications, but can also be placed in any layout.

I've used it, but I've never tried to give *fixed positions* to the subwindows. Anyway it's apparently possible. Probably [`QMdiArea::tileSubWindows`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html#tileSubWindows) is already enough for your requirements.
Set custom titles and bars to the windows is given for free instead:

> QMdiSubWindow represents a top-level window in a QMdiArea, and consists of a title bar with window decorations, an internal widget, and (depending on the current style) a window frame and a size grip. QMdiSubWindow has its own layout, which consists of the title bar and a center area for the internal widget

See the official documentation for further details.